# Local DB for Universal Windows App

Tags: sql, .net, database, win-universal-app

I'd like to know what's the best solution to manage a database into a Universal Windows App. I was used to use SQL Server Compact CE, but of course it's not compatible with UWP. Is there a Microsoft way to do that, which integrates well with Entity ?

Comment: **Use a SQL Server database in a UWP app**
you can try reading this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database for Universal Windows Apps is provided through SQLite. See this example http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/09/08/Using-SQLite-on-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx